# How to make bouncy text carousel CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

The animation that I am trying to replicate:

Here it is at normal speed:

[image]

Here it is at slower speed, so you can see the animation more clearly (I hope)

[image]

Essentially, it bounces off once at `text4`, and once at `text5`.

I am new with animations, so if anyone has any recommendation on how to approach this, it would greatly be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez832tkp/)

Comment: What's wrong with the answer already given? Give it feedback if it doesn't satisfy you so others would know why.

Comment: @Islam Elshobokshy Thanks for the suggestion, I provided feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a gravity-like `cubic-bezier` to imitate the bounce effect. You will apply this `cubic-bezier` per keyframe to mimic acceleration/deceleration like real-life gravity. You can use [this cubic-bezier generator](https://cubic-bezier.com/) to create the acceleration/deceleration you like.

Here's a runnable solution with the compiled CSS. Here's [the link with the SCSS code](https://jsfiddle.net/aepn74m2/1/).

```css
.loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.loading_carousel {
  font-size: 55.02px;
  line-height: 55.02px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.loading_options {
  position: relative;
}
.loading_options.rotate {
  animation: 2s linear 1s infinite rotate;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.loading_element {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.loading_shuffle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 55.02px;
  overflow: hidden;
  mask: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 25%, black 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.36, 0.9, 0.83); /*Accelerate*/
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-240.08px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.4, 0.33, 0.94); /*Decelerate*/
  }
  46.667% {
    transform: translateY(-165.06px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.36, 0.9, 0.83);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translateY(-220.08px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.4, 0.33, 0.94);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translateY(-198.072px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.36, 0.9, 0.83);
  }
  88%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(-220.08px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="loading">
  <div class="loading_carousel">
    <div class="loading_shuffle">
      <div class="loading_options rotate">
        <div class="loading_element">text1</div>
        <div class="loading_element">text2</div>
        <div class="loading_element">text3</div>
        <div class="loading_element">text4</div>
        <div class="loading_element">text5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the existence of `cubic-bezier`, you get my +1

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but close :)
Overall the animation goes like this: Text1 -> Text 5 -> Text 4 -> Text 5 -> Inbetween 4 and 5 -> Text 5

And that's basically your keyframes also I've added the same translate for 50% and 52% which would make it stop for a while at "Text 4"

The rest is mostly adjusting the numbers. (For example I've changed the animation time from 2s to 3s)

```css
.loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 13000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.loading_carousel {
  font-size: 55.02px;
  line-height: 55.02px;
  height: 55.02px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.loading_options {
  position: relative;
}
.loading_options.rotate {
          animation: rotate 3s 1s linear infinite;
}
.loading_element {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.loading_shuffle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 52%;
  text-align: left;
  height: 55.02px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -25px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.loading_shuffle:before, .loading_shuffle:after {
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(#482078));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #482078);
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.loading_shuffle:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -3px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(#482078));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #482078);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-220.08px);
            transform: translateY(-220.08px);
  }
  50%, 52% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-165px);
            transform: translateY(-165px);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-195px);
            transform: translateY(-195px);
  }
  70%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-220.08px);
            transform: translateY(-220.08px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="loading">
    <div class="loading_carousel">
        <div class="loading_shuffle">
            <div class="loading_options rotate">
                <div class="loading_element">text1</div>
                <div class="loading_element">text2</div>
                <div class="loading_element">text3</div>
                <div class="loading_element">text4</div>
                <div class="loading_element">text5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was a mistake on my part for posting the CSS code at first, when I actually needed help doing the animation based on my SCSS. That's why I have updated my question with a Fiddle which contains the SCSS code. Your answer is based on the original question and has the hardcoded values (e.g `-200px`, `-195px` etc). In the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez832tkp/) I'm using variables. Also, the animation in your answer is indeed not perfect, and I need something closer to the animation provided in the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uigvp.gif). Thank you for your efforts.